# Pop-up event reminders in Korganizer, when synchronizing with Google Calendar

Tags: arch-linux, kde, calendar

I have "connected" my Google Calendar with KOrganizer . I create an event within my Google account. I want pop-up reminders to show up when I go home, even though the events weren't created by KOrganizer but were synced. I don't know if I did something wrong, but the events created by KOrganizer don't have pop-ups either. I did check toggle reminder on. Any ideas?

Comment: does the schedule appear on your korganizer ?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same.  Did you solve this?

Comment: I have ditched the app due to this issue, so no

Answer (score 1):

The korgac daemon is responsible for generating the popup reminders from KOrganizer in your desktop environment, in addition to alarms set in KAlarm. The first place to look for an answer to why you're not receiving the alerts from your synced calendar would be to issue this command in a terminal

```
systemctl status korgac
```

If that indicates an error has occurred and the process is not running, use this to find the relevant log entries

```
journalctl -u korgac
```

Problems with korgac can crop up many places, but Dbus is a likely culprit.